# Run multi-query fql in graph api explorer

Tags: facebook-graph-api, fql.multiquery

Trying to run this in the Graph API Explorer:

```
"query1":"SELECT uid, message FROM status where uid in (SELECT uid2 from friend where uid1 = me())"

"query2":"SELECT name from user where uid in (select uid from #query1)"
```

But all I get is:

```
{ "data": [ ]  }
```

I'm completely new into this. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5):

You most likely have a formatting issue

`fql?q={"query1":"SELECT uid, message FROM status where uid in (SELECT uid2 from friend where uid1 = me())", "query2":"SELECT name from user where uid in (select uid from #query1)"}`

Works fine for me.

Comment: Thank you!! I realized I had to have { and } but nothing else, then it worked.